# What is the Card of Bones?

Tags: card-of-darkness

Its only description is “no hoarders.” What does it do?

[image: The Card of Bones]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It prevents the appearance of a monster called Hoarders that appear around the Hushed Well levels. The Hoarder makes you gilded which allows you to gain treasure from any card pickup.